# Show .gitignore files in PhpStorm

Tags: configuration, phpstorm

How can I configure PhpStorm to show in file explorer files added to `.gitignore`?

Currently they are not shown at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHPStorm itself doesn't filter out files added to `.gitignore`. Are you using [.ignore](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore) plugin? Try using **Show ignored files** right-click menu action to show ignored files then:

[image]